# Addition Theorem of Exponential Function Proof Technicality

Tags: complex-analysis

In [*Ahlfors' Complex Analysis 3rd Edition*](https://mccuan.math.gatech.edu/courses/6321/lars-ahlfors-complex-analysis-third-edition-mcgraw-hill-science_engineering_math-1979.pdf) Section 2.3.1, he defines the exponential function as the solution to the differential equation
$$f'(z) = f(z)$$
with initial condition $f(0) = 1$. But then he assumes that $f$ is of the form of a power series (**1. Why can he do this?**) and makes the substitution
$$ f(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \dots + a_n z^n + \dots $$
Then it is easy to see that $a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$, and it is easy to see that $f$ converges on the entire plane. He then goes on to prove the *addition theorem*:
$$e^{a + b} = e^a \cdot e^b ,$$
whose proof I will rewrite here: if we let $D(f)$ denote the complex derivative, then
$$D(e^{z} \cdot e^{c - z}) = e^z \cdot e^{c - z} + e^{z} \cdot \left(- e^{c - z}\right) = 0 ,$$
so $e^{z} \cdot e^{c - z}$ is constant with value $e^{c}$ (found by plugging in $z = 0$), so now the substitution $z = a, c = a + b$ gives the result.

Directly after this proof he makes the following remark:

> We have used the fact that $f(z)$ is constant if $f'(z)$ is identically zero. This is certainly so if $f$ is defined in the whole plane. For if $f = u + iv$ we obtain $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= 0$, and the real version of the theorem shows that $f$ is constant on every horizontal and every vertical line.

**2. Why does $f$ need to be defined on the whole plane, and what is the relevance of the Cauchy-Riemann equations here? I don't understand this remark at all.**

Answer (score 1):

1. If $f’$ exists, then $f$ is holomorphic, and hence analytic.
2. If $f$ were defined on a disconnected set, then $f’ = 0$ may not imply that $f=$ constant, since $f$ could take different values on each connected component. It’s hard to say where the Cauchy Riemann equations come in, since the rest of the remark is cut off.

Comment: Ahlfors only introduced power series a section ago and only proved basic facts about radius of convergence. Is (1) something that is proven readily (the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic part)? Also I edited my post to include the full remark, sorry about that.